# What is the correct way to draw text in different rotation?

Tags: c#, gdi+, system.drawing

I have developed an application to create, edit and print labels. In this application it is possible to insert rectangles in which there are several lines of text and the user can set the font, the color,.., and the orientation among 0°, 90°, 270° and 180° degrees. So I wrote a method to draw the text inside the bounding rectangle, according to the orientation, using GDI+ and DrawString method.

```
 switch (RotationAngle)
            {
                case 90:
                    g.RotateTransform(90);
                    objRec = DrawRectangle.GetNormalizedRectangle(objRec.Top, -objRec.Left,
                        objRec.Bottom, -objRec.Right);
                    g.DrawString(lines[i], textFont, brush, objRec, sf);
                    g.RotateTransform(-90);
                    break;
                case 180:
                    g.RotateTransform(180);
                    objRec = DrawRectangle.GetNormalizedRectangle(-objRec.Left, -objRec.Top,
                        -objRec.Right, -objRec.Bottom); 
                    g.DrawString(lines[i], textFont, brush, objRec, sf);
                    g.RotateTransform(-180);
                    break;
                case 270:
                    g.RotateTransform(270);
                    objRec = DrawRectangle.GetNormalizedRectangle(-objRec.Top, +objRec.Left,
                      -objRec.Bottom, +objRec.Right);
                    g.DrawString(lines[i], textFont, brush, objRec, sf);
                    g.RotateTransform(-270);
                    break;
                case 0:
                    g.DrawString(lines[i], textFont, brush, objRec, sf);
                    break;
            }
```

where "objRect" is the original rectangle set by the user. The method works for all the orientation, but not for 180°! In this case the text is drawn as at 0 degrees. I really don't know what to do and I'm going crazy in finding the correct way to solve the problem. 
What is the correct way to draw text in different rotation?
Any help would be pleasant. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've tried a simplified version of your code (without the `GetNormalizedRectangle()` call) and at 180 the text is drawn rotated; could the bug be in another part of your application? Can you confirm by debugging that `case 180:` is executed?

Comment: I've tryed to debug and the case is executed, but the problem is that it seems that in the 180 case the entire page in which the text is drawn is rotated and all the other objects in the same label are not in their correct position, as if the g.RotateTransform(-180) instruction to restore the state of the graphichs does not work. The same thing doesn't happen for the other orientations, so I really don't know how to manage it!!

Comment: When I draw additional text before and after the switch, I get the correct result for all rotations. Have you checked the rest of your code for rotations of any kind? You could try calling `g.ResetTransform()` before entering the `switch` to see if something changes.